# scala-devel folder persmission Issue if the user is not root user and tmp folder has limited access - java.io.IOException: Permission denied

Tags: scala, ubuntu, permission-denied, tmp

My Ubuntu machine has two user (root and Bikram) and tmp folder has following permission.

```
**drwxr-xr-x   1 root root  tmp**
```

Now I have tried to run `helloworld.scala` (`Console.println("Hello, world!")`) program with the Bikram user in console

```
$scala helloworld.scala
```

But it has thrown following exception

```
java.io.IOException: Permission denied
    at java.io.UnixFileSystem.createFileExclusively(Native Method)
    at java.io.File.createTempFile(File.java:2024)
    at scala.reflect.io.File$.makeTemp(File.scala:29)
    at scala.reflect.io.Directory$.makeTemp(Directory.scala:27)
    at scala.tools.nsc.ScriptRunner.compile$1(ScriptRunner.scala:93)
    at scala.tools.nsc.ScriptRunner.$anonfun$withCompiledScript$2(ScriptRunner.scala:156)
    at scala.tools.nsc.ScriptRunner.runScript(ScriptRunner.scala:124)
    at scala.tools.nsc.ScriptRunner.runScriptAndCatch(ScriptRunner.scala:200)
    at scala.tools.nsc.MainGenericRunner.runTarget$1(MainGenericRunner.scala:63)
    at scala.tools.nsc.MainGenericRunner.run$1(MainGenericRunner.scala:88)
    at scala.tools.nsc.MainGenericRunner.process(MainGenericRunner.scala:99)
    at scala.tools.nsc.MainGenericRunner$.main(MainGenericRunner.scala:104)
    at scala.tools.nsc.MainGenericRunner.main(MainGenericRunner.scala)
```

Same program I have run again with root user it works and inside the tmp folder **scala-develroot** is created.

So how to handle this issue? I don't want to use root as a user and also I can't change the **tmp** folder permission. Is there any way to specify a directory to write **scala-develroot** ?

```
Note : 
root@1a8048217a8f:/tmp# scala -version
Scala code runner version 2.12.2 -- Copyright 2002-2017, LAMP/EPFL and Lightbend, Inc.
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You must be running `scala helloworld.scala` staying inside */tmp* directory which only *root* has access to. The solutions to your problem is to copy `helloworld.scala` to any other directory where user *Bikram* has access to. And run the command staying in that directory.

**Note that `scala` executable should be present as environment variable for user *Bikram* and *SCALA_HOME* variable must be set for user *Bikram***

Moreover you can give *sudo*(root) access to user *Bikram* by doing `sudo usermod -a -G sudo Bikram`